# windows installer xml WIX, in a control, what can the text element be? there are some syntax that I don't understand

Tags: xml, wix

I already know that this is Formatted text, I already read the msdn, but still, I don't understand some of things.

First:

```
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" />
```

what does this Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" means? what means "!" ? and what means "loc."? How can I define my own "loc."?

Second:

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)"
                     X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17">
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
```

what does the innertext "1" means? must we put an "1" into the innertext of a Publish element? because if I put nothing there, this event won't work properly.

Third:
I want to set a value of a property as a text of one of my file, I mean, I want to use a Text in a file as a value of a property. Can I do that?

Forth:
Can I show HTML text in a Text or ScrollableText Control? I mean, how to show HTML Context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the syntax `!(loc.someVariable)` to store strings as variables in order to localize the installer. The WiX manual has a section on [How To: Make your installer localizable](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/make_installer_localizable.html)
2. The inner text of a [Publish element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/publish.html) is a conditional expression. In this case, a '1' always evaluates to true.
3. If you want to set the value of a property to text in a file, you would have to create a custom action to read that file and then set the value of the property.
4. I don't think there is any way to render HTML in the built in WiX controls. You would most likely have to create your own UI using WiX Burn.